# Telethon - Save Telegram channel message as a variable from a NewMessage event

Tags: events, async-await, python-asyncio, telegram, telethon

Having read the following question:
[How to save message from telegram channel as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188530/how-to-save-message-from-telegram-channel-as-variable)

I need to do the same but from a NewMessage event, storing the content of the message in a variable.

However, neither event.text nor event.raw_test seem to be storable in a variable

The following code:

```
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

client = TelegramClient('session', 'api_id', 'api_hash')
client.start()


channel = 'xxx'


async def main():
        @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel))
        async def handler(event):
            await print (event.text)

        await client.run_until_disconnected()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

works printing the new channel message, but it gives me two errors along the printed message:

- await callback(event)
- TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

But when I change

> ```
>         await print (event.text)
> ```

for

> ```
>         msg = await event.text
>         print(msg)
> ```

I get the same two errors but this time nothing is printed...and I need to save the text from the message as a variable in order to continue the script.

It also doesnt work declaring the variable msg before the function and making it global inside it.

I dont know what else to try. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to `await` `print()` neither `event.text`, just use `print(event.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Telethon docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html) covers this quite well (adapted for your use case):

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)

channel = "xxx"

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    print(event.text) # this doesn't need an "await"

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Also notice that I haven't put the event handler in another function, and the run_until_disconnected() call doesn't call any function, nor is it in one.  You don't even need to import asyncio

Answer (score 1):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname) 5s/%(asctime)s] %(name)s: %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARNING)

client = TelegramClient('session', 'api_id', 'api_hash')
client.start()

channel = 'xxx'


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel))
async def handler(event):
    print(event.message.message)


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

You don't need to wrap listener with another async function. And also, you don't need to await print, just use plain print

Comment: `event.message.message` is unnecessary, you can use `event.text`

Comment: Seems like both options work. Both event.message.message and event.text work being stored in a variable, now that I dont await them. Thanks!!